# series of functions converge to continuous function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I don't know how to show that the series: sum(1/(ln(n)n^x)) for n=2 to infinity
converges to a continuous function at (1,infinity)

If it was uniformly converges, I had no problem, but it doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>1$ then
$$\frac1{n^x\ln n}\le \frac1{n^a},\quad\forall x\ge a$$
and the Riemann series $\sum\frac1{n^a}$ is convergent so the given series is uniformly convergent on every interval $[a,+\infty)$ hence it's continuous on the interval $(1,\infty)$.